# Trying to get property of non-object prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am trying to assign a variable inside a controller. I have written this statement in the __construct() function of the controller but I am getting the error trying to get property of non-object. If I remove the statement everything works fine. The statement is okay since that is used to assign variables according to the prestashop documentation but I think it doesn't have to be written in the __construct() function when working with controllers. Does anyone know where should I write the assign statement?

Statement:

```
   $this->context->smarty->assign('message', 'hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the __constructor like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
        $this->context = Context::getContext();
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
}
```

then, define initContent function:

```
     public function initContent()
     {
         $this->context->smarty->assign('message', 'hello');  --> Define here
         parent::initContent();
     }
```